# Set value of string in a shared c_wchar_p in a subproccess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ctypes, shared

I've a situation like this:

The main process generate some sub-process that they should write the result in a shared object in string and numeric types, for the numeric types there's no problem but with the string the value will be lost.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from ctypes import Structure, c_double, c_wchar_p, c_int

# shared obj class
class SharedObj(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('name', c_wchar_p), ('val', c_double) ]

def run_mp( values , lock , s ) :
    for i in range( s , len( values ) , 2 ):
        lock.acquire()
        values[i].name = str( i ) # write the string value in the shared obj
        values[i].val = float( i )
        print( "tmp: %d" % i )
        lock.release()

def main():
    # creating the shared obj and mutex
    values = mp.Array(  SharedObj , [SharedObj() for i in range( 10 )] )
    lock_j = mp.Lock()

    # creating two sub-process form the function run_mp
    p1 = mp.Process( target=run_mp , args=( values , lock_j , 0 ))
    p2 = mp.Process( target=run_mp , args=( values , lock_j , 1 ))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    for v in  values:
        print()
        print( "res name: %s" % v.name )
        print( "res val: %f " % v.val )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As a result the field in the shared object containing the c_double is written in the field, but the string generated in the sub-processes rum-mp ( `string values[i].name = str( i )` ) will be lost in the main process.

There is a method for saving the strings generated in sub-process?

The **output** of this code looks like:

Where the resulting string in the main process are completely random.

```
tmp: 0
tmp: 2
tmp: 3
tmp: 4

res name: ����羍����羍
res val: 0.000000
res name: ����羍����羍
res val: 1.000000
res name:
res val: 2.000000   ....
```

Comment: c_wchar_p - is a pointer type. I bet you a passing pointer from one process to another. And the parent reads data at this address.

Comment: Ok c_wchar_p is a pointer, but how I write my string in the shared object, without losing it?

Comment: @Giggi, as I understand, it is not possible to properly use `c_char_p` or `c_wchar_p` with `multiprocessing`. Refer to this warning in the `multiprocessing` module: "Although it is possible to store a pointer in shared memory remember that this will refer to a location in the address space of a specific process. However, the pointer is quite likely to be invalid in the context of a second process and trying to dereference the pointer from the second process may cause a crash."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing as mp


def run_mp( values ):
    for c_arr, c_double in values:
        c_arr.value = 'hello foo'
        c_double.value = 3.14

def main():
    lock = mp.Lock()
    child_feed = []
    for i in range(10):
        child_feed.append((
            mp.Array('c', 15, lock = lock),
            mp.Value('d', 1.0/3.0, lock = lock)
        ))

    p1 = mp.Process( target=run_mp , args=(child_feed,))
    p2 = mp.Process( target=run_mp , args=(child_feed,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    for c_arr, c_double in child_feed:
        print()
        print( "res name: %s" % c_arr.value )
        print( "res val: %f " % c_double.value )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html There is an example of using Array of chars.

There is also mmap module alowing to share memory http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html but with this you have to Sync access yourself possibly by semaphores. If you like more simple approach just use pipes.

Comment: This code works with python 2, but with python 3 I've this error: ** mp.Array('c','hello world', lock = lock),
 ...... TypeError: one character string expected **

Comment: Traceback (most recent ..):
  File "ct1.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "ct1.py", line 18, in main
    mp.Array('c','hello world', lock = lock),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 259, in Array
    return Array(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 112, in Array
    obj = RawArray(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 89, in RawArray
    result.__init__(*size_or_initializer)
TypeError: one character string expected

Comment: Not yet: **res name: b''** but now I've no errors. And it lost also the numeric value

Comment: There is no point to guess for me why this dont wokr in 3.X blindly. Play around with arguments to mp.Array(ctypes.c_char,15) and docs also says there is .raw attribute on array setting c_arr.raw = 'hello foo' also workd for me. What exactly are you trying to do? A dict in shared memory? If so i think i have one already implemented in c + cython.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with python3, and also the example above dont works [example from py3k docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes)

Comment: Giggi: This will work in Python3 if you change to `c_arr.value = 'hello foo'.encode('latin1')` in `run_mp()` and the `print( "res name: %s" % c_arr.value.decode('latin1'))` in `main()`. This is because in Python3 strings are `utf-8` Unicode by default. The changes I suggested change the encoding to `latin1` temporarily and convert it back to the `utf-8` default before printing. I chose `latin-1` because all 256 possible byte values will be preserved. Just make sure the size of the `mp.Array()` is enough for the longest string expected.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to use `multiprocessing.Array` because of the obvious requirement of needing to specify its size ahead of time. The following works for me instead for having a multiprocessing-compatible `unicode` object. It is tested with Python 2.6 with multiple processes.

```
>>> shared_str = multiprocessing.Manager().Value(unicode, 'some initial value')
>>> shared_str.value
'some initial value'
>>> shared_str.value = 'some new value'
>>> shared_str.value
'some new value'
```

To deal with the author's specific question about sharing a string and a number, a serializable object to store these can perhaps be created and given to `Value` instead.

You may of course object to needing to use `Manager` for this purpose. If so, please provide an alternate solution.