# Python multiprocessing : global variable and the need of lock

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I made a multiprocessing crawler. Below is the simple structure of my code:

```
class abc:
    def all(self):
        return "This is abc \n what a abc!\n"

class bcd:
    def all(self):
        return "This is bcd \n what a bcd!\n"

class cde:
    def all(self):
        return "This is cde \n what a cde!\n"

class ijk:
    def all(self):
        return "This is ijk \n what a ijk!\n"


def crawler(sites, ps_queue):
    for site in sites:
        ps_queue.put(site.all())

messages = ''
def message_collector(ps_queue):
    global messages
    while True:
        message = ps_queue.get()
        messages += message
        ps_queue.task_done()

def main():
    ps_queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
    message_collector_proc = mp.Process(
        target=message_collector,
        args=(ps_queue, )
    )
    message_collector_proc.daemon = True
    message_collector_proc.start()

    site_list = [abc(), bcd(), cde(), ijk(), abc()]
    crawler(site_list, ps_queue)
    ps_queue.join()

    print(messages)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Questions about these codes:
1. At the end line of the `main()`, there is a code `print(messages)` but it doesn't print anything out. Why does it happen?
2. Something hit my head : messages could be screwed up because each process access global variable `messages` at the same time. Will `lock` be needed? or In this case, each process access `messages` in order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call `mp.Process(target=message_collector, args=(ps_queue, ))` you open a new process, in which a new messages object is created, it is updated correctly, but when you try to print it in the main process it is empty, since it is not the same messages object you added data to. you need another synchronization object so that you can share `messages` between processes, see [How to share a string amongst multiple processes using Managers() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290960/how-to-share-a-string-amongst-multiple-processes-using-managers-in-python)

here's a simple example using a Manager.Dict object (not the most elegant or efficient solution but definitely the easiest)

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class abc:
    def all(self):
        return "This is abc \n what a abc!\n"

class bcd:
    def all(self):
        return "This is bcd \n what a bcd!\n"

class cde:
    def all(self):
        return "This is cde \n what a cde!\n"

class ijk:
    def all(self):
        return "This is ijk \n what a ijk!\n"

manager = mp.Manager()
messages_dict = manager.dict()

def crawler(sites, ps_queue):
    for site in sites:
        ps_queue.put(site.all())

def message_collector(ps_queue):
    messages = ''
    while True:
        message = ps_queue.get()
        messages += message
        messages_dict['value'] = messages
        ps_queue.task_done()

def main():
    ps_queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
    message_collector_proc = mp.Process(
        target=message_collector,
        args=(ps_queue, )
    )
    message_collector_proc.daemon = True
    message_collector_proc.start()

    site_list = [abc(), bcd(), cde(), ijk(), abc()]
    crawler(site_list, ps_queue)
    ps_queue.join()

    print(messages_dict['value'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! One question left: no need to `lock` `message_dict`?

Comment: all the values and containers you get from multiprocessing.Manager are thread safe and can be used without any additional synchronization