# How to pass string data between processes using Python's multiprocessing and shared memory with Array('c', fixed_length)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I looked at [past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21290960/12104604) about sharing Python string data using multiprocessing and shared memory, but it seems unresolved.

I know that I can share numbers and arrays between processes with [code like this](https://qiita.com/t_okkan/items/4127a87177ed2b2db148).

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Array, Process
import time

def process1(count,array):
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.3)
        count.value = count.value + 1
        array[count.value - 1] = count.value
        print("process1:"+str(count.value))
        
def process2(count,array):
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.7)
        count.value = count.value + 2
        array[count.value - 1] = count.value
        print("process2:"+str(count.value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = Value('i', 0)
    array = Array('i', 15)
    
    process_test1 = Process(target=process1, args=[count,array], daemon=True)
    process_test2 = Process(target=process2, args=[count,array], daemon=True)
    
    process_test1.start()
    process_test2.start()
    
    process_test1.join()
    process_test2.join()
    
    print(array[:])
    print("process ended")
```

However, I'm not sure how to handle a string data.

Among the answers to the [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21290960/12104604), it was written that using `Array('c', fixed_length)` would be good. But, this question did not get a correct answer.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Array, Process
import time

def process1(count,array):
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.3)
        count.value = count.value + 1
        array[count.value - 1] = "string:"+str(count.value)
        print("process1:"+str(count.value))
        
def process2(count,array):
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.7)
        count.value = count.value + 2
        array[count.value - 1] = "string:"+str(count.value)
        print("process2:"+str(count.value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = Value('i', 0)
    array = Array('c', 15)
    
    process_test1 = Process(target=process1, args=[count,array], daemon=True)
    process_test2 = Process(target=process2, args=[count,array], daemon=True)
    
    process_test1.start()
    process_test2.start()
    
    process_test1.join()
    process_test2.join()
    
    print(array[:])
    print("process ended")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python `C strings` are `bytes` object not strings, python strings are `utf-8` encoded, to put them in a `C array` you need to `encode("utf-8")` them and to read them back you need to `decode("utf-8")` them.

your code has a major concurrency problem, you are not protecting your `count` from concurrent access, two processes reading its value could get the same value, and the processes will just overwrite one another in the array, so you need a lock here.

lastly, if you are writing more than 1 character you need to keep track of an atomic `index` separately, and you need a `terminator` at the end of each string to be able to tell when one string ends and the other starts (i choose `,` for simplicity).

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Array, Process, Lock
import time

def process1(count, array,  index, lock):
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.3)
        with lock:
            buffer_data = str("z" + str(count.value)).encode("utf-8")  # any str
            array[index.value:index.value + len(buffer_data)] = buffer_data[:]
            array[index.value + len(buffer_data)] = b','
            count.value += 1
            index.value += len(buffer_data) + 1
            print("process1:" + str(count.value))
        
def process2(count ,array, index, lock):
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.7)
        with lock:
            buffer_data = str("z" + str(count.value)).encode("utf-8")  # any str
            array[index.value:index.value + len(buffer_data)] = buffer_data[:]
            array[index.value + len(buffer_data)] = b','
            count.value += 1
            index.value += len(buffer_data) + 1
            print("process2:"+str(count.value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = Value('i', 0)
    index = Value('i', 0)
    array = Array('c', 35)
    lock = Lock()

    process_test1 = Process(target=process1, args=[count,array, index, lock], daemon=True)
    process_test2 = Process(target=process2, args=[count,array, index, lock], daemon=True)
    
    process_test1.start()
    process_test2.start()
    
    process_test1.join()
    process_test2.join()
    
    print(array[:index.value].decode("utf-8"))
    print(array[:])
    print("process ended")
```

```
z0,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7,z8,z9,
b'z0,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7,z8,z9,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

the lock in here is protecting both the `count` and `index`, and while the `+=` operation is atomic, you are reading and modifying each one a lot of times and you cannot guarantee all the reads and writes will happen without the variables changing without that lock, `multiprocessing.Queue` has a similar lock to prevent concurrent writes (and i would prefer using `multiprocessing.Queue` over `multiprocessing.Array` for this)